# C++11 and later: shared_ptr for managing system resources provided by a low-level C library

Tags: c++, c++11, binding, gpio

For the last couple years I've predominantly been a C developer with a bit of Python coding here and there. With the amount of contradictory sources I'm struggling to figure out the correct approach to managing system resources in modern C++.

I'm the author of [libgpiod](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/) - a library for controlling GPIOs via the character device (which is the new way of managing GPIOs from userspace, as opposed to now deprecated sysfs interface). The core library code is written in C but I plan to provide bindings for other languages starting with C++11.

I don't want to get into much detail on what GPIOs are but in general a GPIO line is a configurable pin we can control associated with a GPIO chip which usually exposes several lines. The C library models this two-level hierarchy with two core structures: `struct gpiod_chip` and `struct gpiod_line`. Both are only visible to users as opaque pointers manipulated with provided API functions. Internally, the chip is associated with an open file descriptor (the device file residing in */dev/*) and a couple variables containing the object state.

A pointer to an allocated chip object is returned to the user from one of the `gpiod_chip_open()` variants. The user is responsible for freeing the allocated resources with `gpiod_chip_close()`. As with most low-level C code, the user is tasked with managing the resource *handle*. The library is explicitly made thread-aware (in that there's no global state) but not thread-safe.

The chip manages the resources for all line objects associated with it, so my question below is only relevant for chips.

Now from what I've read so far, in modern C++ the new and delete operators should not generally be used manually. My initial idea for a chip class was thus:

```
namespace gpiod {

class chip {

    // [snip!]

private:

    std::shared_ptr<::gpiod_chip> _m_chip;

};

}
```

Which would make the chip class hold a reference to the gpiod_chip object. Copy & move constructors and the assignment operator would simply make use of the shared_ptr's reference counting to allow to freely move and copy the chip object around. When the reference count drops to 0, a custom deleter would call `gpiod_chip_close()` on the C object.

But then I noticed that some people recommend using a factory in such case and letting the users wrap the object in a smart pointer of their choice themselves.

Any advice on what the correct approach for my use case would be as far as modern C++ goes?

Comment: Sorry, too broad. The correct approach depends on the specific use case and requirements of each individual situation. You are the best person to figure out what they are, for your library. In general, try to avoid playing buzzword bingo, and simply pick the correct approach for your situation, ignoring what self-proclaimed experts say. The amazing thing about best practices and correct approaches is that everyone has one of their own.

Comment: The people you mention are suggesting to work under the C++ motto of "don't pay for what you don't need". If it's just as likely for clients to not need shared ownership, as it is that they do, you shouldn't paint them into a corner with a `std::shared_ptr`. You should also consider favoring free functions over members, if all your class does is to forward its calls. [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) makes them part of the interface, with looser coupling.

Comment: Also, there's a [CppCon2014 talk about effective wrapping of C libraries by C++ code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZO0V4Prefc). Give it a watch. It presents some very good points and principles.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use `std::shared_ptr` unless you need the resource to have shared ownership and it appears that in your example that's not the case. Most of the time it is only necessary to use `std::unique_ptr` which will take ownership of a pointer in its constructor then destroy the pointer with `delete` in its destructor. You say your library is implemented mostly in C so the pointer returned by `gpiod_chip_open()` is probably allocated with `malloc` so destroying it with `delete` which be undefined behavior. To solve this, you can specify a custom deleter functor for `std::unique_ptr` will call `gpiod_chip_close()` its destructor rather than `delete`.

You can do something like this:

```
#include <memory>

struct gpiod_chip_deleter {
    void operator()(::gpiod_chip* chip) noexcept {
        ::gpiod_chip_close(chip);
    } 
};

using gpiod_chip_ptr = std::unique_ptr<::gpiod_chip, gpiod_chip_deleter>;

// ...

gpiod_chip_ptr chip(::gpiod_chip_open());

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `std::shared_ptr` only if you actually need shared ownership semantics, which tends to be rare.

> A pointer to an allocated chip object is returned to the user from one
>   of the `gpiod_chip_open()` variants. The user is responsible for
>   freeing the allocated resources with `gpiod_chip_close()`

The C API does not seem to provide shared ownership. There's no need for you to add it, is it?

You should instead use `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter or write your own small wrapper class with move semantics, which has a similar effect but provides a more problem-specific interface. Or you implement such a wrapper class in terms of a private `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter. The key is really to utilise **move semantics**.

Here is an example to understand what that means:

```
class Chip final
{
public:
    Chip() :
        ptr(gpiod_chip_open())
    {
        // throw if gpiod_chip_open reported an error
    }

    // add other constructors for additional variants of gpiod_chip_open()

    ~Chip()
    {
        gpiod_chip_close(ptr); // add nullptr check if gpiod_chip_close requires one
    }

    Chip(Chip const&) = delete;
    Chip& operator=(Chip const&) = delete;

    Chip(Chip&& other) :
        ptr(other.ptr)
    {
        other.ptr = nullptr;
    }

    gpiod_chip* Get()
    {
        return ptr;
    }

private:
    gpiod_chip* ptr;
};
```

That's basically all you need to start. Add other operations (e.g. a move assignment operator) if you need it. You may also want to get rid of the `Get` member function and completely wrap all other API functions inside of the class; it depends on the level of wrapping you require.

> The library is explicitly made thread-aware (in that there's no global
>   state) but not thread-safe.

Correct synchronisation is an entirely different problem, which `std::shared_ptr` could not magically make go away in any case.

All which `std::shared_ptr` guarantees is that the shared-ownership mechanics themselves will work in a multi-threaded context - i.e. that the reference count is safely incremented and decremented and that no multiple deletions occur if the reference count reaches zero.

It does not guarantee that the managed object itself can safely be used from multiple threads. Whether that's safe or not depends on the managed object. If a `gpiod_chip` (that is, its operations) cannot safely be used from multiple threads, then neither could a `std::shared_ptr<gpiod_chip>`.

You would practically have safe access to a `gpiod_chip*` in both thread A and thread B pointing to the same `gpiod_chip`, but you'd still need to synchronise operations on that `gpiod_chip`.

Comment: I only mentioned threads in order to give an idea on the design, but thanks for the answer. As for the std:shared_ptr: I noticed that the experimental C++17 feature - directory_iterator in filesystem namespace uses a shared_ptr internally for the directory handle structure. Also the regex classes do the same. Why would they need shared ownership if I don't?

Comment: @BartoszGolaszewski: I don't know for sure, but according to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator, which the C++17 standard `directory_iterator` is based upon, states that shared state is required for iterator copy semantics, see the part where it says `actual data members will probably be stored in a shared object`. Something similar likely applies to the regex classes. So there *is* a shared-ownership requirement.

Comment: @BartoszGolaszewski: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954257/3313064

Comment: @ChristianHacki: this also happens to be my use case - the C library implements an iterator which allows going over all GPIO chips available in the system. I want to have it in the C++ bindings as well - preferably as an iterator working with the range-based for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact requirements, but is there any problem in making `chip` non-copyable, just movable?

```
class chip {
  int* handle;
public:
  chip(const chip&) = delete;
  chip& operator=(const chip&) = delete;

  chip(chip&& c) { operator=(std::move(c)); }
  chip& operator=(chip&& c) {
    handle = c.handle;
    c.handle = nullptr;
    return *this;
  }

  chip() : handle(gpiod_chip_open()) { }

  ~chip() { gpiod_chip_close(handle); }
};
```